A hat puzzle question—how to prove the standard solution is optimal?
I am currently writing an essay on hat puzzles, and for the warm-up section I introduce some of the standard finite hat puzzles. One of these proceeds as follows:

You and two friends are each given a tan or gray  hat, determined in each case by a coin flip. Nobody knows their own hat color, but everyone can see the other two. At the bell, everyone will either announce a guess as to their own color or remain silent. The three of you win, as a team, if at least one person guesses correctly and nobody guesses incorrectly. So you will lose if everyone is silent or if someone makes a wrong guess. What is your best chance of winning? You may arrange a strategy before the coins are flipped and the hats given out, but of course there is no communication allowed after that.

Of course you can win with at least fifty percent chance just by agreeing that a designated person says "tan" regardless, and nobody else says anything. But actually, you can do better by following the strategy: if someone sees two hats of the same color on the others, then guess the opposite color for yourself. This will be correct in 6 out of the 8 possibilities, if you think about it, so this is a 75% chance of winning.
My question is: how can we prove this solution is optimal?
I'd like to claim that no strategy directing the players to make an announcement or be silent can achieve a winning percentage greater than 75%, but I've realized that I don't actually know how to prove this.

https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hat-guessing

It doesn't say that the three people are men, but, if they are, we can call this the Man-hat-tan puzzle.

@GerryMyerson There are times when I wish the system allowed us to downvote comments.

@bof, the system does allow us to flag comments for moderator attention.

@bof: You could always ignore my.. err.. son...

Fascinating question... When I saw the title, I thought first it is about a tiling (can be a.k.a. puzzle) by the hat monotile :)

@JoelDavidHamkins I remember reading a very nice essay on hat puzzles on AMS Notices - unfortunately I cannot locate it anymore. But it ended with a nice problem that shows that - under certain assumptions - it is possible to predict the future

Namely, assume the history of the universe is a function $\mathbb{R} \to S$, where $S$ is the set of states and the input variable is time. An oracle is a function $o$ that gives you, for each partial history $g_s \colon ]-\infty, s[ \to S$, a continuation to a function $g = o(g_s) \colon \mathbb{R} \to S$ that agrees with $g_s$ on the common domain.
Then when you know the actual history of the universe, call it $h$, you can get the oracle $o(h_s)$, where $h_s$ is the restriction of $h$ to $]-\infty, s[$. We say that the oracle predicts the future at $s$ if $o(h_s)$ and $h$ agree on (segue)

...agree on an interval $]-\infty, t[$ for some $t > s$.
The theorem is then that there exists an oracle such that, whatever is the actual history of the unverse, it predict the future at $s$ for all $s \notin B$, where $B$ is a denumerable set of bad times

I don't have the article reference anymore, but if you are interested I remember the (very simple) proof

@AndreaFerretti This is the theorem of Hardin and Taylor, available at Christopher S. Hardin and Alan D. Taylor. A peculiar connection between the axiom of choice and predicting the future. Amer. Math. Monthly, 115(2):91–96, 2008. I am also writing about this theorem in my book---I call it the nearly perfect prediction theorem---and I have another summary article planned on it. And yes, I agree, it is a wonderfully surprising result, my favorite kind of theorem, where the proof is elegantly simple and yet the result totally surprising.

@AndreaFerretti By the way, if you could give me a reference to that Notices article, I would be very grateful, since I had a plan to write a Mathematical Shorts column for the Notices giving a brief account of this very theorem, but if it has already appeared in the Notices I shall write on something else. But I can't find anything yet in Notices.

Maybe I remember it wrong. It was something I read by randomly browsing in the library some 15 years ago or so. The proof stuck, but the reference has evaporated from my brain. I am not 100% certain it was Notices, and I cannot locate it anymore, so I suggest you go on anyway. Sorry I cannot be more helpful

Perhaps it was the Hardin Taylor article, which is Math Monthly, and it also has hat puzzles in it.

Suppose we have some mixed strategy for this hat puzzle. For each of the $8$ possible hat assignments and each of the $3$ people involved, we can ask about the probability that the person guesses correctly conditional on that hat assignment, and the probability that they guess incorrectly. After specifying this, we'll have assigned a probability to every possible (world state, person 1 accuracy, person 2 accuracy, person 3 accuracy) tuple, where the world state can be in one of 8 arrangements, and each person's accuracy can be graded as "correct", "silent", or "incorrect".
For a single person, their expected probability of being correct (conditional on venturing a guess) is always 0.5 - that is, the total probability of all outcomes in which they guess correctly must equal the total probability of all outcomes in which they guess incorrectly.
In order for an outcome to lead to a success, we need at least one correct guess and no incorrect guesses. So the probability of success in the puzzle is at most the sum of P(correct) across all three people.
Meanwhile, an unsuccessful outcome can have at most three incorrect guesses, because there are only three people. So the probability of failure is at least one-third as large as the sum of P(incorrect) across all three people.
But for each person, P(correct) = P(incorrect)! So we know that the success probability is at most three times the failure probability, which bounds our success rate by 0.75.

I'm sorry, I don't quite get it. Can you explain a little more fully? What do you mean by putting a probability mass on worlds? I guess you just mean the probability that the putative superior strategy wins in that event. But this is not an individualized thing, so I don't quite get the focus on individual perspectives that you mention.

Sorry if this was poorly explained! I was trying to cover the case of mixed strategies, but it's easier to talk about in the deterministic case.
For any deterministic strategy, I'll be able to say for each of eight possible hat assignments and each of three people whether that person was right conditional on that hat assignment. Because every instruction I give to a hat-wearer forces their choice in worlds where they're right as well as worlds where they're wrong, I'll always have as many "correct" cells in this 8x3 grid as "incorrect" cells.

Yes, my question is about the deterministic case, not probabilistic mixed strategies. But I guess it would be a stronger result to handle mixed strategies.

Since I win for every row with at least one "correct" and no "incorrect"s, the best I can hope for is to get 6 rows with a single "correct" and 2 rows each with three "incorrect"s - because if I had 7 or more rows used up on being correct, I wouldn't have room to fit my ≥7 incorrect guesses.

Here's a simple table of this allocation in the standard solution; we have 6 correct answers and 6 incorrect answers, distributed across 6 and 2 world states respectively.

@JoelDavidHamkins I've reworded the original answer in the hopes of making things clearer as to how this plays out for mixed strategies.

If you play the same game with 4 people, the same argument shows that a winning probability of 75% is the best possible. Can you do better with greater numbers of people? Or is 75% always the best possible for $\ge3$ people?

@bof The three-person strategy can be generalized to an approach which saturates this bound whenever the number of participants is one less than a power of $2$. Given a Hamming code on strings of length $2^n-1$, each person ventures a guess only if what they see is compatible with the arrangement forming a codeword, and guesses whichever color on their hat would not lead to a codeword. Since all strings are either a codeword or exactly one bit-flip away from a codeword, this leads to success on all non-codeword inputs.

Very nice, thanks! By the way, I don't see the point of considering mixed strategies when the enemy's strategy is known.


The choice of a triple of strategies is essentially a one-player game, so there is no advantage to mixing.  2.  Your argument generalizes quite nicely to give the result in the "edited to add" section of my own answer.


Excellent answer, it gives insight into this class of problem where you want no failure in order to win : you have to fail as hard as you can on a few bad cases. (Here all 3 players fail at the same time, allowing them to win on 3 different games)

Thanks for the edit---an elegant answer.

I find all the mixed strategy stuff an irrelevant distraction. The main point I take is: every instance of someone guessing correctly must be balanced by an instance of that person making the same judgement but being incorrect. So if we win six rows, there must be at least six instances of incorrect guess, and this uses up the remaining slots in the other two rows. So winning seven is impossible.

Suppose you and your two friends have names A, B, C.
For each case, assign a 3-letter string for what colours the people get. For example, TGG means A gets tan while B and C get gray.
Suppose when A sees two tan hats, there is probability $A_T$ that A guesses tan.
When B sees two tan hats, there is probability $B_T$ that B guesses tan.
When C sees two tan hats, there is probability $C_T$ that C guesses tan.
$Pr(\text{win|TTT})\le\text{expected number of correct guesses}=A_T+B_T+C_T$
$Pr(\text{win|GTT})\le1-A_T$ since there is probability $A_T$ that A guesses wrong
$Pr(\text{win|TGT})\le1-B_T$ since there is probability $B_T$ that B guesses wrong
$Pr(\text{win|TTG})\le1-C_T$ since there is probability $C_T$ that C guesses wrong
Therefore, $Pr(\text{win|TTT})+Pr(\text{win|GTT})+Pr(\text{win|TGT})+Pr(\text{win|TTG})\le3$ so $Pr(\text{win|at least two tan})\le3/4$. Similarly, $Pr(\text{win|at least two gray})\le3/4$ so $Pr(\text{win})\le3/4$.

There are 8 states of the world.  Suppose that (with deterministic strategies) they win in 7 of those 8 states.
Then they either win in every state where A's hat is gold or in every state where A's hat is tan.  Assume the former.
It follows that A never guesses tan.  Likewise there is a color that B never guesses and a color that C never guesses.   Let the colors they never guess be X, Y, Z.  It follows that they lose in the state XYZ, so (because they win in 7 states) they must win in all other states.
Now consider what happens in the state X'Y'Z' (with all colors changed to their opposites).  This is not the same as XYZ, so they must win in this state, which means somebody guesses correctly in this state.  Let it be A.  Then whenever A sees Y'Z', they must guess X'.  But then they're wrong half the time.
Edited to add:  Similar reasoning (and/or a generalization of RavenclawPrefect's argument) shows that the probability of a win is bounded above by $n/(n+c-1)$ when there are $n$ players and $c$ equally likely hat colors.

I'm confused. You say, assuming the supposed 7/8 strategy wins whenever A is gold, that it follows A never guesses tan. But why is that exactly? Perhaps A does so in two cases, one of which is the 1/8 losing case, and the other is part of the winning 7/8.

Note: my colors were tan/gray, not gold.

@JoelDavidHamkins :  A never guesses tan in any of the cases GGG,GGT,GTG,GTT.  But A's guess can only depend on B's and C's hats, so he also never guesses tan in TGG,TGT,TTG,TTT.

Ah yes, I see. Very clear.

@JoelDavidHamkins :  I should add also that there's clearly no advantage to randomizing.  Let STU be a triple of strategies that maximizes the probability of  a win.  Call that probability p.  Then clearly no probability distribution over triples of strategies can yield a probability higher than p.

I'm making this a separate answer though it's really just a concise version of my earlier one:
Suppose there are 7 winning states.  Let XYZ be a winning state in which both A and B name colors.  Then X'YZ and XY'Z are both losing states, contradiction.  Therefore in any winning state, at most one player names a color.  Therefore there are at most 4 winning states (indexed by the possibly empty set of players who name colors in that state), contradiction.

In October 2023, a book was published that is entirely about hat puzzles. The answer to your question is also in it. The title of the book is "De kabouterformule" ("The Gnome Formula"). The book, published by Prometheus, is written in Dutch, but if you have the e-book, you can perhaps have it translated automatically? (The author of the book is myself, apologies for this shameless self-promotion.)

Consider the game with $n$ players, and identify the possible assignments of hat colours with vertices of the $n$-dimensional hypercube graph. Given a (deterministic) strategy, let $S$ be the set of vertices where the strategy suceeds.
I claim that for any vertex $v$, the $n+1$ vertices in $N^+(v)=\{v\}\cup N(v)$ cannot all be included in $S$: if $N^+(v)\subseteq S$, then in situation $v$, the strategy must make everybody silent, as any possible anouncement of the $i$th player is inconsistent either with $v$ or with the $u\in N(v)$ that differs from $v$ in $i$th coordinate. But then the strategy fails in $v$ after all, a contradiction.
This implies
$$|S|\le\frac n{n+1}2^n:$$
if the probability that a randomly chosen vertex $v$ belongs to $S$ is $p>n/(n+1)$, then by linearity of expectation, the expected number of elements of $N^+(v)\cap S$ is $(n+1)p>n$, thus there exists a vertex $v$ such that $|N^+(v)\cap S|\ge n+1$, a contradiction.
For $n=3$, we get $|S|\le6$.
Conversely, if $S$ is a set of vertices such that $N^+(v)\nsubseteq S$ for all $v$, then there exists a strategy that succeeds on $S$, defined as follows. For a given player, let $u$ and $v$ be the two neighbouring vertices consistent with what the player observes. If exactly one of $u$ and $v$ belongs to $S$, say $w$, let the player announce the colour corresponding to $w$; otherwise the player remains silent. If $v\in S$, then in situation $v$, no player can announce an incorrect colour, and the condition $N^+(v)\nsubseteq S$ ensures that all players cannot remain silent.

Assume you have a strategy winning on at least $7/8$ cases.
Each player can see $4$ configurations, and whenever they speak on a certain configuration, they lose with probability $50$%. It follows that every player can speak at most in one configuration.
But then there are at least $8 - 3 \times 2 = 2$ cases in which all players are silent, and hence they lose, contradiction.
